# Find out the biggest odd number from three arguments in a function [Python]

Tags: python, function

I need to write a function that will print biggest odd  number from three input arguments.

Here is my code.

```
def oddn(x,y,z):
odd_number_keeper = []
for item in x,y,z:
    global odd_number_keeper
    if item % 2==1:
        odd_number_keeper = [item]
        return max(odd_number_keeper)
    else:
        print 'No odd number is found'
```

My codes seem is not working. Any ideas how i can modify this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes would be needed:

```
def oddn(x,y,z):
    odd_number_keeper = []
    for item in [x,y,z]:
        if item % 2==1:
            odd_number_keeper.append(item)
    if not odd_number_keeper:
        print 'No odd number is found'
        return
    return max(odd_number_keeper)
```

Iterate over the values `x`, `y` and `z` and add the odd numbers to `odd_number_keeper`. If there are any numbers then you return the `max()` of the elements in this list of odd numbers. If there are no odd numbers then you print the message and return (without a result, as there is no number to return).

Answer (score 1):

You have to first filter all odd-numbers and then call `max`:

```
def oddn(x,y,z):
    odd_numbers = [item for item in (x,y,z) if item%2==1]
    return max(odd_numbers)
```

or in short:

```
def oddn(*numbers):
    return max(x for x in numbers if x % 2 == 1)
```

also it is not good practice, if you want to print some message on error:

```
def oddn(*numbers):
    try:
        return max(x for x in numbers if x % 2 == 1)
    except ValueError:
        print 'No odd number is found'
        return None
```

Comment: Thank you,Daniel. But how can i print 'No odd number is found' in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are not finding the biggest odd number from the list, instead, you are finding the first odd number and returning that. The issue is in the lines -

```
odd_number_keeper = [item]
return max(odd_number_keeper)
```

you first need to be appending item to the list, insteading of making `odd_number_keeper` the list with only that item.

Secondly, the return statement should be at the end of the function, not inside the for loop.

You need a code something like -

```
def oddn(x,y,z):
    odd_number_keeper = []
    for item in x,y,z:
        if item % 2==1:
            odd_number_keeper.append(item)
    return max(odd_number_keeper)
```

Comment: Thank you,Man. Your suggestion helped me to get this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting **odd_number_keeper** each time. You probably meant

```
odd_number_keeper += [item]
```

Also the `return` and `print` should be at the end of (outside) the for loop.
(please fix indentation to be clearer on your intent).

Answer (score 0):

Solving it using filter. Doing it in pythonic way.

```
def oddn(a, b, c):
    final = []
    final.append(a)
    final.append(b)
    final.append(c)
    result = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, final)
    return max(result)
```